# How to get a route closure working in jQuery express

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, closures

I'm trying to set up a bunch of routes in jQuery that call the same function but with a different parameter.  I'd like to do this in a functional manner to make it easier to read, extend, etc...

Before:

```js
app.get('/p/:p1',             p1);
app.get('/p/:p1/:p2',         p2);
app.get('/p/:p1/:p2/:p3',     p3);
app.get('/p/:p1/:p2/:p3/:p4', p4);
```

What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```js
var path = '/p';
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
  path += '/:p' + i;
  debug('adding path for "%s"', path);
  app.get(path, function(req, res) { p(i, req, res) });
}
```

Unfortunately, `p()` is always called with `i = 5`, no matter which route it takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a a new scope where the value of `i` is locked, otherwise the loop will finish and `i` will be what it was set to last when the async `app.get()` executes

```
var path = '/p';
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
  (function(j) {

      path += '/:p' + j;
      debug('adding path for "%s"', path);
      app.get(path, function(req, res) { p(j, req, res) });

  })(i);
}
```

Comment: i'm confused, i thought the block in the for loop was its own scope.  so, if i define a var inside a for loop, i cannot access it outside.  how is this different?

Comment: There's no special scope in a for loop, but the issue isn't accessing the variables, the issue is that the loop executes and finishes right away, but the app.get() executes at a later time, and at that time the value of i is 5 as the loop has long since completed. Locking the value of i in a IIFE where it's passed as an argument fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to have `p()` return a function instead:

```js
var path = '/p';
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
  path += '/:p' + i;
  debug('adding path for "%s"', path);
  app.get(path, p(i));
}

function p(i) {
  return function(req, res) {
    debug('i = ' + i );
    // ....
  };
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, i need to know the value of i inside the function.

Comment: You _do_ get the value of `i` inside the function. That's how scoping works in JavaScript.